# CLI Java program as a service

Tags: java, service, command-line-interface

I am planning to make a CLI Java program/server that will run as a service on Raspbian and it will start at boot...

I would like to make it as MySQL service for example...

MySQL I can start by command:

```
service mysqld start
```

or stop it by:

```
service mysqld stop
```

I found Apache Commons Daemon lib which can help me with that...

But what I need there in addition is that I can work with the instance, created by the service, in (different) command line, same as with MySQL for example:

```
mysql --version
mysql --help
etc
```

So any ideas how to make it? You can post some useful articles... I came across some articles but I didn't find how can I access the instance in command line...
Everywhere is just how to start a service...

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1**

You can do this by having your java application start/stop by a script Ex: `shell` or `perl`

In the script file you can build the command to start/stop your service [app]
Say your application can be started using `java -cp "." com.test.Main`

In `startService.sh`

```
...
// build classpath, specify heap, perm gen space, encoding
...
java <classpath> <vm_args> <memory> com.test.Main
...
```

**Answer 2**

There is a way in `spring-boot` to configure `telnet/ssh`, also to write own commands to interact with it.

need to add the artifact `spring-boot-starter-remote-shell`, authentication also possible

This doc reference might help [SSH or Telent Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-remote-shell)

[image: spring-boot SSH]

Comment: Firstly, thanks for response. Ok, but this just start a service, right? But I need to access the instance, in fact, what the service creates... Assume that we have com.example.AwesomeServer class... An instance of this class will be created in com.test.Main when I call startService.sh or so as you said... simply I start service by `service awesomeserverd start` and now I would like to work with that instance in command line as: `awesomeserver --help` ... From you example I cannot read how to make it...

Comment: Is it like a socket programming? This might help https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/app-hello-world-server.html

Comment: You start a server [service] , clients can exec commands on it using some port

Comment: In your case `awesomeserver` will be a wrapper that connects to the server using a port